# How to retrieve data from two different Database System using node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, oracle

Like I want to show some data which is in oracle database and some data which is in MongoDB database(I am using MongoDB and node.js).How to Merge these two Database and show the output?

I don't how to start for this...

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to query both databases separately and join the result in your server?

Comment: In single query I should do the joining and show the result .

Comment: How do you imagining querying two different databases with one query?
You always have two calls, one to each database.

Comment: sorry for the trouble. I thought of using merge.Then How to do the querying for two different databases and join the result :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Querying from two databases boils down to (generally) merging two result arrays, one from each db. You can use a similar approach to the code below, in this case I'm just using simple objects to represent the dbs, however the approach is exactly the same.

```js
let database1 = {
    query: function(queryText) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve([{user_id: 1, name: "John Smith"}, {user_id: 2, name: "Mary Jones"}]), 100));
    }
}

let database2 = {
    query: function(queryText) {
        return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(() => resolve([{user_id: 1, dob: "1966-05-22"}, {user_id: 2, dob: "1979-11-01"}]), 100));
    }
}

function mergeResults(result1, result2, key) {
      var obj = result1.concat(result2).reduce((acc, v) => {
        acc[v[key]] = Object.assign(acc[v[key]] || {}, v);
        return acc;
    }, {}); 
    return Object.values(obj);
}

async function queryAndMerge() {
    let result1 = await database1.query("get all users");
    console.log("Result from db. 1: ", result1);
    let result2 = await database2.query("get all users");
    console.log("Result from db. 2: ", result2);
    let mergedResult = mergeResults(result1, result2, "user_id");
    console.log("Merged results: ", mergedResult);
}

queryAndMerge();
```